# Strength of forces between bar-magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields

Where can I find a math-formula to calculate the force between two bar-magnets which are near each other, i.e., at a distance which is comparable to their lengths ??  Until now, all the formulas which I've been able to find say that they don't work unless the distance between the two magnets is large when compared to their size.

Comment: You could visualize the electrostatic equivalent and then find the forces using Coulomb's law on the 4 charges without taking the long distance assumption.  In other words, see the derivation of electric field on equatorial position of dipole just don't apply the distance assumption.

Comment: I'd do it by experiment.

Comment: I like SmarthBansal's idea, though the law that emerges will be messy algebraically and only approximate because: (1)  point poles are only an approximation, (2) some magnetic domains in one magnet may be temporarily  reversed or altered in size by the proximity of the other magnet.  If I really wanted to know, I'd find out by experiment!

Comment: More on force between two magnets: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+force+two+magnets

Comment: Hi, Smarth, and thanks for replying !!  You say that I could visualize the electrostatic equivalent and then use Coulomb's law.  Is this the equation which you have in mind ??   F = (μ*q1*q2) /(4π*d^2)  ... I've seen this, but don't know how to use it.  All I can figure out is that the dimensional-units of q1 and q2 are amp-meters.  Can you explain what amp-meters are, so I can get a clue re how to use them, or where to find them ??